# About this determinant $|\lambda I − B(I + vu)|$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

$B$ is a complex $n\times n$ matrix. $u$ is $1 \times n$ and $v$ is $n \times 1$.

I have the following determinant:
$|\lambda I − B(I + vu)|$.

According to my textbook, if $\lambda$ divides this determinant, then $B$ or $I + vu$ is singular. Why is that the case?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to give more context. For example, what do you mean by $\lambda$ dividing the determinant? Are you dealing with only integers here, since we can always factor $\lambda$ out of any polynomial, provided $\lambda\ne 0,$ and we're dealing outside the integers.

Comment: Unfortunately, my textbook is very concise. So this is really all I have.

Comment: In this context, it means $\lambda$ as a monomial divides $f(\lambda)$ as a polynomial. Otherwise "divides" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @EminOzkan I still feel something may be gained from knowing the exact statement made. Can you *quote* the full statement? Oh, never mind. I see you're already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the determinant
$$f(\lambda)=|\lambda I-B(I+vu)|$$
is a polynomial in $\lambda$. If $\lambda$ divides $f(\lambda)$, then $\lambda$ is a factor of $f(\lambda)$, i.e. $0$ is a root for $f(\lambda)$. Hence
$$f(0)=|B(I+vu)|=|B||I+vu|=0$$
At least one of $|B|$ or $|I+vu|$ is $0$. Now recall that a square matrix is nonsingular iff it has a nonzero determinant and you have your conclusion.

Comment: Very clear explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your determinant is the characteristic polynomial of $B(I+vu)$.
The assumption means that its constant term is $0$. But hte constant term of the characteristic polynomial is the determinant , up to a sign. Hence $\det(B(I+vu))=0=\det(B)\det(I+vu)$.

Thus, $\det(B)=0$ or $\det(I+vu)=0$ and we are done.

Comment: Thanks, "Your determinant is the characteristic polynomial of B(I+vu). " I failed to see this before